# querying a another column from different table

Tags: php, mysql

i want to query a column `gravatar_email` from table `users` i want to do this while using this query

```
SELECT 
    u.username, u1.maxword, MAX(u.date_created) as date,user_id
FROM
    user_records u
        INNER JOIN
    (SELECT 
        username,DATE(date_created) date_created, MAX(wordpermin) AS maxword
    FROM
        user_records
    GROUP BY username,DATE(date_created)) u1 ON u.username = u1.username
        AND u.wordpermin = u1.maxword AND Date(u.date_created) = DATE(u1.date_created)
WHERE
    DATE(u.date_created) = CURDATE()
GROUP BY (username)
ORDER BY maxword DESC
LIMIT 20
```

this query is calling data from one table named `user_records` and both tables have column named  `username` so i would like to use it to call `gravatar_email`

Answer (score 1):

Join with `users` to get the `gravatar_email` column.

```
SELECT 
    u.username, u1.maxword, MAX(u.date_created) as date,user_id, users.gravatar_email
FROM
    user_records u
INNER JOIN
    (SELECT 
        username,DATE(date_created) date_created, MAX(wordpermin) AS maxword
    FROM
        user_records
    GROUP BY username,DATE(date_created)) u1 ON u.username = u1.username
        AND u.wordpermin = u1.maxword AND Date(u.date_created) = DATE(u1.date_created)
INNER JOIN users ON users.username = u.username
WHERE
    DATE(u.date_created) = CURDATE()
GROUP BY u.username
ORDER BY maxword DESC
LIMIT 20
```